# is this ok to use AssemblyScript in React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, assemblyscript

I have a question about using AssemblyScript  in React project
I already read some stuff about using AssemblyScript to increase performance but the question is when my project is not that big sth like a game or machine learning etc when I have a less computational project, is that ok to use AssemblyScript to increase performance for better user experience? if yes could you please tell me where and when it's better to use it?

Comment: It depends on what you want to write in it. Most of the time performance advantage will be neglectable, but code will be more challenging to read.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [page](https://www.assemblyscript.org/frequently-asked-questions.html#frequently-asked-questions) on the official AssemblyScript website that goes into a few scenarios that you may encounter and if it would make sense to use AssemblyScript or Javascript, or both, for performance reasons.

The main idea is, as you stated, that you benefit more from AssemblyScript if you have a compute-intensive application, a game or a webgl application, and for a blog or manipulating the DOM you can get away with using JavaScript.

As always with performance problems, you have to benchmark the result in practice.